# jquery .get causing TypeError

Tags: jquery, get, typeerror

I have the following jQuery .get statement:

```
$.get("handleAppt.php", { recordID: "<?php echo $recordID; ?>", firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, email: email, apptMonth: apptMonth, apptDay: apptDay, apptYear: apptYear, apptHour: apptHour, apptMinute: apptMinute, apptAMPM: apptAMPM, selectedCarYear: "<?php echo $selectedCarYear; ?>", selectedCarMake: "<?php echo $selectedCarMake; ?>", selectedCarModel: "<?php echo $selectedCarModel; ?>", selectedCarValue: "<?php echo $selectedCarValue; ?>", downPayment: "<?php echo $downPayment; ?>" }, function(data) {
    alert("done");
});
```

When the code executes, I get the following message in firebug:

> TypeError: Not enough arguments to EventTarget.addEventListener.
>   http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js?_=1375363591188

For the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong with the .get statement.

EDIT:

Source view of .get:

```
$.get("handleAppt.php", { recordID: "24337", firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, email: email, apptMonth: apptMonth, apptDay: apptDay, apptYear: apptYear, apptHour: apptHour, apptMinute: apptMinute, apptAMPM: apptAMPM, selectedCarYear: "2013", selectedCarMake: "Toyota", selectedCarModel: "RAV4", selectedCarValue: "22452", downPayment: "0" }, function(data) {
     alert("done");
});
```

Comment: Look at what's actually sent *to the browser*, and you're likely to find the problem. Looking at the PHP source is unlikely to help.

Comment: And you're sure it's the $.get statement that is the issue ?

Comment: Have you take a look at the generated source "view-source" and checked so your php echos dosen't break the object?

Comment: Pretty sure @adeneo is on to something there, I don't believe `$.get` does any `addEventListener` calls at all (with the arguments shown).

Comment: If i comment out the entire .get statement, I get no errors in the console.

Comment: Due, try with $.post, may be because, you are sending big query string which is not suited for $.get

Comment: If that's the case, I'm betting you have mismatched quotes in the outputted strings that mess up a surrounding event listener ?

Comment: I tried .post - same result

Comment: tried setting variables outside of the .get so I could use variables instead of quotes in the variable declaration area of the .get - same results

Comment: Okay, i figured it out - I took out all the variables being passed, and it worked.  So i went through 1 by 1 and added them back in.  Turns out one of my variables was defined as an object instead of a value.